# Which join is suitable for my Ajax data table in CI

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I have two tables one is 'sales' and another is 'deliveries'. I have a report which shows all 'sales'. I want to do a join where i can get all sales which are not delivered comparing to the deliveries table, only where the ID is the only key point. Although I am new developer for CI, i want to know how to do it.

Below is the code returning values in the grid.

```
function getdatatableajax()
   {
        if($this->input->get('search_term')) { $search_term = $this->input->get('search_term'); } else { $search_term = false;}

       $this->load->library('datatables');
       $this->datatables
            ->select("sales.id as sid, date, reference_no, biller_name, customer_name, total_tax, total_tax2, total, internal_note")
            ->select("sales.id = deliveries.id as sid date, reference_no, biller_name, customer_name, total_tax, total_tax2, total, internal_note")
            ->from('sales');
            $this->datatables->add_column("Actions", 
            "<center><a href='#' title='$2' class='tip' data-html='true'><i class='icon-folder-close'></i></a> <a href='#' onClick=\"MyWindow=window.open('index.php?module=sales&view=view_invoice&id=$1', 'MyWindow','toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=1000,height=600'); return false;\" title='".$this->lang->line("view_invoice")."' class='tip'><i class='icon-fullscreen'></i></a> 
            <a href='index.php?module=sales&view=add_delivery&id=$1' title='".$this->lang->line("add_delivery_order")."' class='tip'><i class='icon-road'></i></a>
            <a href='index.php?module=sales&view=pdf&id=$1' title='".$this->lang->line("download_pdf")."' class='tip'><i class='icon-file'></i></a> 
            <a href='index.php?module=sales&view=email_invoice&id=$1' title='".$this->lang->line("email_invoice")."' class='tip'><i class='icon-envelope'></i></a>
            </center>", "sid, internal_note")

        ->unset_column('sid')
        ->unset_column('internal_note');

       echo $this->datatables->generate();

   }
```

The Deliveries tables has below fileds

id  date    time    reference_no    customer    address     note    user    updated_by

I just want the alerted code where it will works ny just doing joins, if applicable.

Comment: Any one want to furnish a nice answer ? Plz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code, its should work.

```
function getdatatableajax()
   {
        if($this->input->get('search_term')) { $search_term = $this->input->get('search_term'); } else { $search_term = false;}

       $this->load->library('datatables');
       $this->datatables
            ->select("sales.id as sid, sales.date as date, sales.reference_no as reference_no, sales.biller_name as biller_name, sales.customer_name as customer_name, sales.total_tax as total_tax, sales.total_tax2 as total_tax2, sales.total as total, internal_note as sintnote")
            ->from('sales')
            ->join(deliveries, 'sales.reference_no = deliveries.reference_no', 'left');
            $this->datatables->add_column("Actions", 
            "<center><a href='#' title='$2' class='tip' data-html='true'><i class='icon-folder-close'></i></a> <a href='#' onClick=\"MyWindow=window.open('index.php?module=sales&view=view_invoice&id=$1', 'MyWindow','toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=1000,height=600'); return false;\" title='".$this->lang->line("view_invoice")."' class='tip'><i class='icon-fullscreen'></i></a> 
            <a href='index.php?module=sales&view=add_delivery&id=$1' title='".$this->lang->line("add_delivery_order")."' class='tip'><i class='icon-road'></i></a>
            <a href='index.php?module=sales&view=pdf&id=$1' title='".$this->lang->line("download_pdf")."' class='tip'><i class='icon-file'></i></a> 
            <a href='index.php?module=sales&view=email_invoice&id=$1' title='".$this->lang->line("email_invoice")."' class='tip'><i class='icon-envelope'></i></a>
            </center>", "sid, internal_note")

        ->unset_column('sid')
        ->unset_column('internal_note');
       echo $this->datatables->generate();

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Ref Number is the Invoice number compare to the Sales table in generally. So try this code below and may it will furnish what you really want to populate from the DB.

```
   function getdatatableajax()
   {
        if($this->input->get('search_term')) { $search_term = $this->input->get('search_term'); } else { $search_term = false;}

       $this->load->library('datatables');
       $this->datatables
            ->select("sales.id as sid, date, reference_no, biller_name, customer_name, total_tax, total_tax2, total, internal_note")
            ->from('sales')
            ->join(deliveries, 'sales.reference_no = deliveries.reference_no', 'left');


            $this->datatables->add_column("Actions", 
            "<center><a href='#' title='$2' class='tip' data-html='true'><i class='icon-folder-close'></i></a> <a href='#' onClick=\"MyWindow=window.open('index.php?module=sales&view=view_invoice&id=$1', 'MyWindow','toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=1000,height=600'); return false;\" title='".$this->lang->line("view_invoice")."' class='tip'><i class='icon-fullscreen'></i></a> 
            <a href='index.php?module=sales&view=add_delivery&id=$1' title='".$this->lang->line("add_delivery_order")."' class='tip'><i class='icon-road'></i></a>
            <a href='index.php?module=sales&view=pdf&id=$1' title='".$this->lang->line("download_pdf")."' class='tip'><i class='icon-file'></i></a> 
            <a href='index.php?module=sales&view=email_invoice&id=$1' title='".$this->lang->line("email_invoice")."' class='tip'><i class='icon-envelope'></i></a>

            </center>", "sid, internal_note")

        ->unset_column('sid')
        ->unset_column('internal_note');

       echo $this->datatables->generate();

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do. It's a very crude form, but you get the idea.

```
//Select everything
$this->db->select (  '*'  );

//From sales
$this->db->from ( 'sales as s' );

//Where id of sales is equals to your id
$this->ci->db->where ( 's.id', $id );

//Join where id in sales is equals to id_sales in deliveries
$this->ci->db->join (  'deliveries as d', 's.id = d.id_sale' );

// Query
$query = $this->ci->db->get (  );
```

Comment: Are you sure here 'where' is required ?

Comment: @Sashi Well, if op is looking to get all the records then where is not needed, but since he/she mentioned *Id is the key point*, the where clause is required, that is how we can recognize a record in the sales table.

Comment: SELECT `sales`. *
FROM sales
LEFT OUTER JOIN deliveries ON sales.id = deliveries.id
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 0):

> I just want the alerted code where it will works ny just doing joins, if applicable.

I didn't quite understand this but I think you're looking for a query that shows all sales that haven't been delivered yet.

To answer your question, a *LEFT JOIN* is appropriate because it'll return a result set even if the matching row isn't found in *deliveries*.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sales s
LEFT JOIN deliveries d ON d.id = s.id
WHERE d.id = null;
```

Actually, any one of these queries will work for you - [Opposite of inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420982/opposite-of-inner-join?answertab=votes#tab-top)